# An example of Gateaux derivative

Tags: derivatives, gateaux-derivative

In one of the Gateaux derivative examples mentioned [here](http://www.math.ttu.edu/~klong/5311-spr09/diff.pdf) on page 5, it is mentioned that the function $f(x) = \lvert x\rvert $ has the Gateaux derivative defined at $x=0.$ In particular, it says that   $$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac {\left\lvert {\epsilon h} \right\rvert} {h} = \left\lvert h \right\rvert $$

I feel that the above limit is not unique. It can be either $ +h  \text{ or}  -h $. The Gateaux derivative is not defined at $x = 0$

Comment: I would not trust your cited source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition 
$$
d_hf(0)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{f(\epsilon h)-f(0)}{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{|\epsilon h|}{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{|\epsilon| }{\epsilon}|h|.
$$
You wrote $h$ in the denominater instead of $\epsilon$. And here you see that the limit doesn't exists because
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{|\epsilon| }{\epsilon}|h|=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}|h|=|h|\neq-|h|=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^-}-|h|=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^-}\frac{|\epsilon| }{\epsilon}|h|.
$$
So there is a mistake in your reference.